# Why does SUM(mycolumn) display decimal point?

Tags: sqlite

In an SQLite database, I created a table and imported CSV data into it.

The last column only contains integers:

```
ZIP;AMOUNT
78123;4272
95456;154
etc.
```

I used the following commands:

```
.mode csv
.separator ';'
CREATE TABLE MyTable("ZIP" TEXT,  "AMOUNT" INTEGER);
.import input.csv MyTable
sqlite> select SUM(AMOUNT) from MyTable;
25270.0
```

Why is SQLite displaying SUM with a decimal?

Thank you.

===

Edit: Here's the infos:

```
sqlite> select typeof(AMOUNT) from MyTable LIMIT 10;
text
integer
integer
integer
integer
etc.

sqlite> select typeof(SUM(AMOUNT)) from MyTable;
real
```

==

Edit: Here's the top of input.csv as exported from LibreOffice Calc:

```
ZIP;AMOUNT
78123;4272
95456;154
etc.
```

Maybe I didn't use the right commands to import data into SQLite.

Comment: Show result of `select typeof(AMOUNT) from MyTable;` and `select typeof(SUM(AMOUNT)) from MyTable;`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce it: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9efd2748240ebc900e738ed57ac15a09

Comment: Your first line for `select typeof(AMOUNT) from MyTable LIMIT 10;` is `text`. Could it be `ZIP;AMOUNT` imported as row, but not as header? [Documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html): If any input to sum() is neither an integer or a NULL then sum() returns a floating point value

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll make sure SQLite doesn't import the header as a record.

Comment: *"The result of total() is always a floating point value. The result of sum() is an integer value if all non-NULL inputs are integers. **If any input to sum() is neither an integer or a NULL then sum() returns a floating point value which might be an approximation to the true sum.**"*   Are you ok with the fact that `SUM()` value might be possible approximation on money related data????

Answer (score -1):

@PetSerAl has it. Because you're importing into an existing table, every line is imported including the header. That string makes `sum()` return a floating point result.

I work around this case with:

```
.import '| tail -n +2 input.csv' mytable
```

which strips the first line.

If the first character of the filename is a `|`, it's treated as a shell command to run (Using the C `popen()` function) and its output is used as the data to import.

Comment: Thanks much. It doesn't work on Windows, but I get the idea.